# TypeError: Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a problem while making a chrome extension. It gives me an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined". I was doing it by [Chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Background script:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});
```

Content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(sender.tab ?
              "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
              "from the extension");
  if (request.greeting == "hello") sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Test app",
  "permissions": [ "background", "tts", "storage", "webNavigation", "activeTab", "tabs" ],

  "background": { "scripts": ["my.js"] },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "my.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost; object-src 'self'",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["autofill.js", "smart.js"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: Can you change `console.log(arguments);` in place of `console.log(response.farewell)` and let us know if you are seeing any output or not ?

Comment: Can you add `return true` to the onMessage event Handler and see if it works

Comment: Do you have `"tabs"` or `"activeTab"` permission in your manifest? Does the content script tab's console show any output?

Comment: @shojibur Arguments [callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]

Comment: @IvánNokonoko both of them

Comment: @shojibur well, it has no errors, but it doesn't print anything. Also I need to return a string value back (my task)

Comment: How is your content script injected? Can you post your manifest.json file?

Comment: Hmm.. Seems like content script does not inject , would you please post manifest file ?

Comment: @shojibur Sure. I've updated the question!